# find letter within string and get positions - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

The goal is to find if the letter 'a' is within a string and add the three positions away from the 'a' occurrences within the string.

So if the string was 'gabe' my list would look like this list = [2,3,4].
If the string is 'gabba' then list = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

my current code seems to be giving me errors

```
def nearby_az(string)
list = []
for i in 0..(string.length)
    if string[i] == 'a'
        list.push(i+1)
        list.push(i+2)
        list.push(i+3)
        next
    end
return list
```

end

I get the following error:
(repl):11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

can you see where my logic falls off?

Comment: You'd need one more ```end``` to close out the function definition.

Comment: "can you see where my logic falls off?" – Ruby tells you that it's a *syntax* error. Since the code cannot even be parsed, it also obviously cannot be executed, and thus, this cannot possibly have anything to do with your logic, since your logic never even gets executed.

Comment: I spent an hour yesterday but didn't get what I was doing wrong. Good thing i asked here sooner rather than later. that was all I needed - and extra 'end'!

Comment: This happens sometimes, @hac13. Some of the worst errors to find are the easier ones.

Comment: But there are more points to be made better in this code of yours than just the **end**, as you may see by Cary's answer and mine own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact you haven't closed the range block with an **end**. But there are other points. I suggest you to try something like this:

```
def nearby_az(str)
  list = Array.new
  pos = -1
  str.each_char do |c|
    pos = pos + 1
    if (c == 'a') then
      list.push(pos+1)
      list.push(pos+2)
      list.push(pos+3)
    end
  end
  list
end
```

or yet better

```
def nearby_az(str)
  list = Array.new
  nstr = str.each_char.to_a
  nstr.each_index do |i|
    if (nstr[i] == 'a') then
      list.push(i+1)
      list.push(i+2)
      list.push(i+3)
    end
  end
  list
end
```

(This ways you don't even have to create an artificial index, by using the natural index of the **nstr** array)

With this code, if you do

```
puts nearby_az("asdfgaqwer")
```

the result will be [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8], as desired.

Remember you don't need a **return** in Ruby. The value of the last expression calculated in a method is returned by default to the method caller.

Of course you may continue using your way, doing this:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  list = []
  for i in 0..(string.length)
    if string[i] == 'a'
      list.push(i+1)
      list.push(i+2)
      list.push(i+3)
    end
  end
  list
end
```

And it will give you the same result, although I think the first code is a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more Ruby-like way you could do that.

**Code**

```
def indices(str)
  str.each_char.
      with_index.
      select { |c,_| c=='a' }.
      flat_map { |_,i| (i..i+2).to_a }
end
```

**Examples**

```
indices "gabe"
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
indices "gabba"
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
indices "abbadabbadoo"
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
str = "gagga"
```

Then the steps are as follows:

```
enum0 = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "gagga":each_char> 
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "gagga":each_char>:with_index>
```

Carefully examine the above return value. You can think of `enum1` as a *compound enumerator* (though Ruby has no such concept--`enum1` is simply an enumerator). We can see the elements of `enum1` that will be passed to `select` by converting `enum1` to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["g", 0], ["a", 1], ["g", 2], ["g", 3], ["a", 4]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = enum1.select { |c,_| c=='a' }
  #=> [["a", 1], ["a", 4]] 
a.flat_map { |e,i| (i..i+2).to_a }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)'s block variables are `e` and `i`. When the first element of `a` (`["a", 1]`) is passed to the block, the block variables are assigned using *parallel assignment*:

```
e, i = ["a", 1]
  #=> ["a", 1] 
e #=> "a" 
i #=> 1
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
(i..i+2).to_a
  #=> (1..3).to_a
  #=> [1,2,3]
```

Note that `flat_map` is equivalent to:

```
b = a.map { |e,i| (i..i+2).to_a }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
c = b.flatten(1)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

One last thing: `flat_map`'s first block variable, `e`, is not used in the block calculation. As is common in such situations, `_` (a legitimate local variable) is used instead for that variable. That informs the reader that that block variable is not used, and may also reduce the chances of introducing errors within the block.

Comment: Excellent answer! I suggest the OP accepts your answer instead of mine! Thank you so much for the opportunity to learn more Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, @EddeAlmeida, but don't forget the OP is encouraged to select the answer that was most helpful to him or her. You explained the problem with the OP's code, I didn't, and sometimes improvements to a familiar approach are appreciated more than an altogether different way of addressing the problem. My answer was as much for other readers than for the OP.

Comment: In the end the OP selected no answer at all... LOL

Comment: sorry guys, new here. I didn't notice the part about accepting answers :P
you guys are great though!